Which operators do non-invertible symmetries correspond to in quantum mechanics?
In quantum mechanics, symmetry transformations are usually assumed to correspond to unitary operators in the Hilbert space. However, recently there has been an increasing interest in "non-invertible symmetries". Unitary operators can not represent these symmetries since otherwise I can find an inverse by taking the Hermitian conjugate.
My question is: What operators do these symmetries correspond to in the Hilbert space?

where has there "recently been an increasing interest in 'non-invertible symmetries'"? What is the definition of such a symmetry?

can you give an example of a non-inversible symmetry?

Related: Why should symmetries be described by invertible transformations? and AccidentalFourierTransform's answer.

TASI Lectures on Non-Invertible Symmetries, Non-Invertible Symmetry Talk

"Non-invertible symmetries are ubiquitous in 1+1d. They are implemented by codimension-1 topological defects in spacetime, and therefore are 0-form global symmetries".

@bolbteppa it would be nice if any of the people who do understand the topic of the question could be bothered to add enough context to the question so that everyone can understand it (or understand at least that it is a legitimate line of inquiry in contemporary physics).

What is a non-invertible symmetry?
You already know what a local operator is: $\phi(x)$ is local because its support is a point $x$. You also know what a line operator is: for example, a Wilson line $W(\gamma)$ is a line operator because its support is a line $\gamma$.
More generally, a $p$-dimensional operator $O(\Sigma)$ is an operator whose support is a $p$-dimensional submanifold of spacetime. If $\Sigma$ is a point, $O$ is a local operator; if it is a line, $O$ is a line operator; if it is a surface, $O$ is a surface operator; etc.
We say that an operator $O(\Sigma)$ is topological if its dependence on $\Sigma$ is topological: correlation functions $\langle O(\Sigma)\cdots\rangle$ are invariant under small deformations of $\Sigma$.
The canonical example of a topological operator is
$$
U(\Sigma)=e^{\int_{\Sigma} j}
$$
where $j$ is a conserved current: $\mathrm dj=0$. This is topological due to Stoke's theorem: if we change $\Sigma\to\Sigma+\delta\Sigma$, then $\int_\Sigma j\to\int_\Sigma j+\mathrm dj\equiv\int_\Sigma j$. So $U$ depends on $\Sigma$ in a very mild way. If $\Sigma$ is a spatial slice in flat spacetime, then topological invariance is just the statement that $U$ does not depend on the time slice, i.e., it is a conserved operator. This is just a restatement of Noether's theorem.
Note that topological operators are more general than Noether's theorem: for example, discrete symmetries also lead to topological operators, even though they are not the exponential of a local current.
What is a symmetry, then? The traditional definition, a symmetry is an invariance of the Lagrangian, is not very complete, since it does not work on non-Lagrangian theories. So the modern definition of a symmetry is that there exists a topological operator. This includes the old notion -- whenever you have a conserved current you automatically get a topological operator -- but goes beyond that, to include symmetries that do not come from a current, and it also includes theories without an action formulation.
The "issue" with this modern definition is that the set of topological operators does not in general form a group. In particular, we are not guaranteed that every topological operator has an inverse. If the topological operator comes from a conserved current, then such an inverse exists, namely
$$
U(\Sigma)^{-1}=e^{-\int_\Sigma j}
$$
But if the topological operator is of the more general kind, the inverse need not exist. If it doesn't exist, then we call the corresponding symmetry "non-invertible".
You might be bothered that non-invertible symmetries are too pathological, but this is not quite true: they imply much of the same constraints as invertible symmetries: there are Ward identities, spontaneous symmetry breaking, 't Hooft anomaly matching, etc. All the power of regular symmetries is also present in the non-invertible case, although extracting these constraints is a much more involved issue, and this is an active area of research. So the conclusion is, non-invertible symmetries should not be ignored, you can learn from them just as much as you can learn from regular symmetries, although in practice it is usually very hard.
Higher form symmetries
We say that a topological operator $O(\Sigma)$ implements a $p$-form symmetry if $\Sigma$ is codimension $p+1$. So a regular symmetry, where $\Sigma$ is $d-1$-dimensional, corresponds to a zero-form symmetry. A higher form symmetry is a symmetry where $p>0$.
A $p$-form symmetry naturally acts on $p$-dimensional operators: a zero-form symmetry acts as $\phi(x)\to\phi'(x)$; a one-form symemtry acts as $W(\gamma)\to W'(\gamma)$; etc. So the usual notion of a symmetry, which acts on the local fields of the theory, corresponds to a $0$-form symmetry. If you only care about correlation functions of local operators, you might as well ignore the existence of higher form symmetries. But if you care about line operators, or more generally other extended operators, then higher-form symmetries constrain their correlation functions in the same way regular symmetries constrain correlation functions of local operators. So for example, if you care about confinement, you better pay attention to one-form symmetries, since confinement is a statement about the expectation value of Wilson lines.
So a $p$-form symmetry is, by definition, an extended operator $O(\Sigma)$ whose support is a codimension $p+1$ submanifold $\Sigma$, and whose dependence thereon is topological. This symmetry is invertible if $O(\Sigma)$ admits an inverse, and non-invertible otherwise.
Discrete Symmetries
One can, sometimes, be a little more explicit. Consider a regular symmetry, by which I mean an invertible zero-form symmetry. If the symmetry is continuous, we know how to construct the corresponding topological operator: we just exponentiate the integrated Noether current.
Is there a similar construction in the case of discrete symmetries? Kind of, but it is a little more abstract. (It has to be, abstraction is the price of generality).
We consider a specific example, $\phi^4$ theory. We know that there is a discrete symmetry $\phi\to-\phi$. Then, there must be an associated topological operator that I will call $C(\Sigma)$. We can define this operator via its matrix elements. In other words, if we come up with a recipe to evaluate $\langle C(\Sigma)\cdots\rangle$, where $\cdots$ stands for any operator insertion, then we have effectively defined $C(\Sigma)$ itself, albeit in an indirect way.
Say that $\Sigma$ is closed (the open case defines monodromy defects and these are more complicated, I do not want to get into that). We then declare: $\langle C(\Sigma)\cdots\rangle$ is given by performing the path integral over all field configurations $\phi(x)$, but subject to the following rule: if $x$ is inside $\Sigma$, we replace $\phi\to-\phi$ in $\cdots$.
Of course I could use the same definition in whatever theory I want to: I can always define an operator $C(\Sigma)$ by declaring that fields inside $\Sigma$ should be taken as $-\phi$ instead of $\phi$. But such a construction defines a topological operator only when the action is invariant under $\phi\to-\phi$. The intuitive reason is that $\phi$ is discontinuous across $\Sigma$, and this costs energy unless the action does not care about the discontinuity in the first place.
So this leads to a general rule: if your theory is invariant under a discrete symmetry $\phi\to\phi'$, then you can always define a topological operator by declaring that $\phi$ becomes $\phi'$ when $x$ crosses $\Sigma$. This defines an operator in any theory, but it is topological if and only if the path integral does not care about the discontinuity. This is why topological operators are very often called topological defects: they implement discontinuities in the fields.
This is in fact part of a more general story, where a symmetry is basically the same as a boundary condition. (Here by b.c., I don't mean that the manifold is open; instead I mean that there are non-trivial cycles of various degrees). I will only sketch the general argument and you will have to look elsewhere for the details.
For example, imagine that your manifold is a cylinder. Then, you need to declare what happens to your fields as you go around the $S^1$. The obvious boundary condition is $\phi(x+2\pi)=\phi(x)$, but this is not the only option. If $\phi\to\phi'$ is a symmetry of your theory, then the choice $\phi(x+2\pi)=\phi'(x)$ also defines a valid boundary condition: the equations of motion are still consistent, inasmuch as the action is still single-valued.
We call such b.c.'s twisted boundary conditions, and the Hilbert space that you obtain by quantizing in the presence of such b.c. the twisted Hilbert space. In this sense, you can also define a symmetry to be any boundary condition that leads to a well-defined path integral.
In pictures, one can define the twisted Hilbert space as the space obtained by quantizing on $S^1$ with a topological defect that intersects $S^1$ at some point (instead of wrapping this cycle). Which point does not matter -- the defect is topological so it can be moved around. This construction implements the twisted boundary condition, because as you take $\phi$ around $S^1$, you will intersect the defect once, and therefore the end-result is $\phi'$.
The same discussion holds, mutatis mutandis, for higher form symmetries. This is actually how one-form symmetries were first described: 't Hooft imposed a very funny boundary condition for gauge fields on the torus. In modern terminology, such boundary conditions correspond to twisting the theory by its one-form symmetry.
(There is part of an even larger story: twisted boundary conditions are equivalent to turning on a background for the symmetry, at least in the discrete case. Indeed, a flat connection is defined by its holonomies. Again we leave this to further reading...)
This same construction also holds for non-invertible symmetries, although of course the most general version of the statement has not been worked out yet. At least in free theories, people have shown in very explicit terms that you can obtain non-invertible topological defects by patching up fields, in a discontinuous manner, across submanifolds of various dimensions. This also works in interacting theories, but it is harder to write down explicit formulas.
Non-invertible symmetries and projectors
In QM, spacetime is just the real line, parametrized by the time coordinate. Hence, topological invariance of $O(t)$ simply means that $O$ is time-independent. In other words, in QM a symmetry is anything that commutes with the Hamiltonian, which you may recognise as the usual definition.
Note that this definition does not require the operator to be invertible: indeed, it is easy to construct operators that commute with $H$ but that do not have an inverse. The simplest example is a projector. Indeed, anything that projects states into some (but not all) eigenspaces of $H$ will commute with $H$, but it will not have an inverse (since it annihilates states that are in the orthogonal complement of those subspaces).
In fact it is not hard to argue that all non-invertible symmetries in QM are projectors, which makes them a little boring. More generally, there is a certain folk theorem (which can be proven in certain cases) that non-invertible zero-form symmetries are only interesting in $d=2$ dimensions, non-invertible one-form symmetries are only interesting in $d=3$ dimensions, etc. This is why non-invertible zero-form symmetries are most studied in 2d CFTs: this is where they are the most interesting. Which doesn't mean they do not exist in other dimensions; they definitely do, they are just a little more boring.
Spontaneous symmetry breaking
Exactly like regular symmetries, generalized symmetries can break spontaneously too, whether zero-form or higher form, whether invertible or non-invertible.
Breaking a continuous symmetry gives you a massless particle, as in the usual Goldstone phenomenon. If the symmetry has degree $p$, then the NG particle has spin $p$. So for example, the photon can be interpreted as the massless particle that arises when you spontaneously break a continuous one-form symmetry, much like a phonon is the massless particle that arises when you break a zero-form symmetry. (You might wonder if gluons are the NG boson of a non-abelian one-form symmetry; the answer is no: all higher-form symmetries are always abelian, since there is no notion of ordering for submanifolds of codimension higher than 1).
Breaking a discrete symmetry gives you degenerate vacua and "domain walls". The correct language to discuss these degenerate vacua is that of TQFTs. Discrete SSB gives you a TQFT; if $p=0$ the TQFT has topological local operators (which correspond to vacua on $S^{d-1}$); if $p=1$ the TQFT has topological line operators (which correspond to vacua on $S^1\times S^{d-2}$), etc.
SSB also has similar effects for non-invertible symmetries, but the discussion gets very abstract very fast. In the continuous case a non-invertible version of Goldstone theorem has been reported in the literature, although the conclusion seems weaker than in the invertible case, which probably means that we haven't been able to extract all the useful information out of the symmetry, and more works needs to be done. In the discrete case a lot of work has been done, specially in $d=1+1$, where the various patterns of SSB are described in category theory language (where the vacua are modules of a certain fusion category yadda yadda). I have only very superficial knowledge on this topic so I will stop here.
One final point
There is one final subtle point, of which I won't go into details but I want to mention anyway. See Shu-Heng's lectures in the comment section for more details.
There is a trivial construction of non-invertible symmetries of any degree, in any number of spacetime dimensions, that goes as follows. Say that we have two invertible symmetries $U_1(\Sigma)$ and $U_2(\Sigma)$. This means that we have two operators that depend on $\Sigma$ topologically, and they each has its inverse. Then we can define a third operator
$$
U_3(\Sigma):=U_1(\Sigma)+U_2(\Sigma)
$$
which is obviously still topological -- each term is -- but it need no have an inverse. (This is just the statement that the sum of two invertible matrices need not itself be invertible).
Non-invertible symmetries of the type above are very boring: they do not teach us anything that the invertible symmetries $U_1,U_2$ already do. So a better definition of a non-invertible symmetry is: a topological operator that does not have an inverse, and that it cannot be written as the sum of invertible topological operators. In fact, this is still not the full story: we want to demand that a non-invertible defect cannot be written as an integral linear combination of invertible defects. Why this is a good condition, you will have to go read the lectures.
In order for this mysterious condition to be meaningful in the first place, we must have some notion of normalization for $U_1,U_2$, otherwise we can always rescale them in order for any linear combination to become an integral linear combination. And here is the kicker: $p$-form symmetries admit a meaningful normalization only when $p\le d-1$. This normalization is obtained by requiring the twisted partition function to admit a twisted Hilbert space interpretation (in the sense I described above); but $(d-1)$-form symmetries do not admit a twisted Hilbert space in the first place, and therefore they do not admit a good notion of integrality.
So it is not entirely meaningful to ask whether a $(d-1)$-form symmetry is invertible or not. So for example, in $d=1$ (a.k.a QMs), we cannot really ask whether a zero-form symmetry is invertible or not. We can of course ask whether it has an inverse or not, but the full definition of non-invertible symmetry is a little more subtle than that. We would need to study the defect Hilbert spaces, but they do not exist in QM, so we cannot really say whether it is a good non-invertible symmetry according to the proper, full definition above.
Which is to say, the question in the OP, while entirely reasonable, is ultimately not well defined.
